# Using Python to find the intersection of two equations

Tags: python, math

So I used this to Plot to equation to see where the lines intersected:

```
figure()
x = linspace(0, 50, 10)
cost = 3.5 * x + 90
revenue = 7 * x
plot(x, cost, 'r')
plot(x, revenue, 'b')
legend(('cost', 'revenue'), loc=2)
title('Analysis')
show()
```

Now I am having issues finding a method that shows what the intersection is, whether graphically or showing the point in an output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Calculate the intersection with basic math, then create a one point scatter plot.

Comment: I suppose that would be a way to get the point to show up, but I was hoping there was a way to have python calculate the point from the equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment above you write:

> but I was hoping there was a way to have python calculate the point from the equations?

You could use [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/solvers/solvers.html) which makes it straightforward to calculate the point of intersection:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
solve(3.5*x + 90 - 7*x, x) #right hand side is 0 and we solve for x
```

which gives you the desired output

```
[25.7142857142857]
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is what I was hoping for.  I knew it was simple, but I could not get something to work for me!